# CSS Translate animation jumps without transition on IOS

Tags: html, ios, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm making html5 photo presentation. 
The presentation has 11 slides and 3-8 differently animated elements on each slide.
Demo page is here http://frontrend.ru/test/for-iframe.html

Firstly, I made all the animations with **margin** property. But them worked not smooth on IOS. Then I changed it to **translate** animations, which playing perfect on desktop, but jumpes from state to state on IOS.

For example animations of the first slide:

```
@keyframes bottom-top-slow {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -100%);
  }
}

#prst_s1_1_layer {
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_2_layer {  
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .05s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_t1_layer {  
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .1s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_t2_layer {   
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .15s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_3_layer {   
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .2s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_4_layer {   
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .2s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_t3_layer {   
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .25s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_5_layer {   
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .3s;
  }
}

#prst_s1_logo_layer {   
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
  .state-1 & {
    animation: bottom-top-slow 4.5s .35s;
  }
}
```

All the elements jumps to `transform: translate(0, 0);` without transition.

**UPD**
All elements have class layer to translate relatively to parent.

```
.prst_layer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried positioned the element (`position: 100%`), instead of using `transform: translate(0, 100%);`?

Comment: Have you mentioned `top: 100%;` ?
I have tried `margin-top: 100%;` earlier but it shivers.

Comment: Sorry, meant `top: 100%` ... :)

Comment: Just tried top and left - shivers

Comment: Ok, can't help further as I don't have iOS